# Force OpenGraph "Crawler" from Facebook, to "jump to another url"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Hy guys, is there any way to force the facebook crawler to jump to another URL. (With Javascript)
Example: I have canonical Facebook URL's for Like Buttons and more.
They Looks like this:

http://www.harddance.at/eventdetails/45/PreStylerz+Excalibur+Ybbs

On the Page, i create Anchor Navigation URL's, like this:

http://www.harddance.at/#/eventdetails/45/PreStylerz+Excalibur+Ybbs

When i add an "og:url" meta, the Crawler Jump to the given page, and search for Metatags.
Is there another "Build in" way, with Javascript, to force Facebook to do this.

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Way, i found out now is, replace #, with #!. Facebook make an "escaped_fragment" and send it as GET param to the Page. example.com/#!/test/id Facebook would parse: example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=/test/id And there, i could create my OpenGraph Tags!

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do URL rewriting :)

Answer (score 2):

"*is there any way to force the facebook crawler to jump to another URL. (With Javascript)* "

With javascript?  Nope.  Facebook's linter doesn't process javascript.

You will need to implement URL rewriting on your server.  There are many ways to do so, and it depends on your server environment to determine the one that will work for you.